# Setting the path of images in writing a Thesis

Tags: graphics, paths, thesis

I am writing a thesis with two chapters.  Each chapter is a separate journal paper and has its own text and one single image. I put the text and image of each chapter in a separate file:

`Chapter_1_Folder:  Includes  Chapter_1.tex   and Image_Name.eps`

`Chapter_2_Folder:  Includes  Chapter_2.tex   and Image_Name.eps`

Although the image files have the same names (Image_Name) but they are totally different images.

I know that the ".tex"  files are loaded with the following commands

`\input{chapter_1_Folder/Chapter_1}`

`\input{chapter_2_Folder/Chapter_2}`

How should I set the path of images for Latex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simper would be to have separate image names, but if you want the same name, do

```
\graphicspath{{chapter_1_Folder}}
\input{chapter_1_Folder/Chapter_1}

\graphicspath{{chapter_2_Folder}}
\input{chapter_2_Folder/Chapter_2}
```

then

```
\includegraphics{Image_Name}
```

in each file.